# Uploading audio files with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble uploading audio with the carrierwave gem, when i post the the audio file all that displays is the audio url link. First time using the gem and not sure if i am using carrierwave correctly. Just trying to display the audio file on the show page.

```
  class AudioUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  include CarrierWave::Audio

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

---

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @music.title %>
  <%= @music.audio.url() %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_music_path(@music) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', musics_path %>
```

---

music.rb

```
class Music < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :audio, AudioUploader
end
```

---

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170606155943) do

  create_table "musics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "audio"
  end

end
```

---

music controller

```
class MusicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_music, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /musics
  # GET /musics.json
  def index
    @musics = Music.all
  end

  # GET /musics/1
  # GET /musics/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /musics/new
  def new
    @music = Music.new
  end

  # GET /musics/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /musics
  # POST /musics.json
  def create
    @music = Music.new(music_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @music.save
        format.html { redirect_to @music, notice: 'Music was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @music }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /musics/1
  # PATCH/PUT /musics/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @music.update(music_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @music, notice: 'Music was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @music }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @music.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /musics/1
  # DELETE /musics/1.json
  def destroy
    @music.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to musics_url, notice: 'Music was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_music
      @music = Music.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def music_params
      params.require(:music).permit(:title, :audio)
    end
end
```

Comment: how about putting the url into an `<audio>` tag? It would be `<audio controls src="<%= @music.audio.url %>"></audio>`

Comment: @maxpleaner just tried it the audio file created but only 3 seconds and no sound is playing

Comment: @maxpleaner ok so i just uploaded another audio file and it works thank

Comment: Thanks, @jmike and maxpleaner, I implemented this in my rails project with help from your question :) Shouldn't this be marked as answered though?